# Exam : Extras space above and below question

Tags: spacing, multicol, exam

I'm trying to write exam paper using Latex, sample tex file is mentioend below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,answers,11pt]{exam}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{nonfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{%
\settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 0em}
}
\TileWallPaper{\paperwidth}{1\paperheight}{dummy}
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\medskip\par}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]
    \node[
      shape=circle,
      fill,
      inner sep=1.5pt,
      text=white,
      minimum size=1.5em
    ] (char) {#1};
}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\circled{\thequestion}}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question How did he solve the problem?
\begin{multicols}{2} \begin{choices}
\choice He searched for food.
\choice He ate a carrot from the nearby farm.
\choice He ate a carrot from the snowman's nose.
\choice He ran away.
\end{choices} \end{multicols}
\question Which pair has rhyming words?
\begin{multicols}{2} \begin{choices}
\choice lunch, nibble
\choice little, chubby
\choice suppose, stick
\choice man, ran
\end{choices} \end{multicols}
\question Which of these is a noun?
\begin{multicols}{2} \begin{choices}
\choice hungry
\choice nibble
\choice bunny
\choice grabbed
\end{choices} \end{multicols}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

It's output is mentioned below:

[image]

There is extra space coming above & below question (highlighted in orange box in the image) can you please suggest how to (1) reduce space above the question (2) reduce space below the question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to `\setlength{\multicolsep}{0.2em}` suggested by Ruedi (which changes the vertical distance below the question), you also need `\setlength\itemsep{-.7\baselineskip}` which changes the distance between two questions. For a change, I have used `etoolbox` and its `\AtBeginEnvironment` macro. Adjust the values as your needs, but be careful not to make things ugly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,answers,11pt]{exam}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{multicols}{\vspace{-.7\baselineskip}}             %%   adjust this

\newcommand*\circled[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]
    \node[
      shape=circle,
      fill,
      inner sep=1.5pt,
      text=white,
      minimum size=1.5em
    ] (char) {#1};
}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\circled{\thequestion}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\setlength\itemsep{-.7\baselineskip}                                %%   adjust this
\question How did he solve the problem?
\begin{multicols}{2} \begin{choices}
\choice He searched for food.
\choice He ate a carrot from the nearby farm.
\choice He ate a carrot from the snowman's nose.
\choice He ran away.
\end{choices} \end{multicols}
\question Which pair has rhyming words?
\begin{multicols}{2} \begin{choices}
\choice lunch, nibble
\choice little, chubby
\choice suppose, stick
\choice man, ran
\end{choices} \end{multicols}
\question Which of these is a noun?
\begin{multicols}{2} \begin{choices}
\choice hungry
\choice nibble
\choice bunny
\choice grabbed
\end{choices} \end{multicols}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0.2em}
```

This command shall be put somewhere below your "\usepackage" commands.